# Compiling PHP Extension with correct API Version on Windows

Tags: php, c++, c, php-extension, borland-c++

I have *finally* created a very simple "Hello World" style PHP Extension dll on windows, after immeasurable hassle.  However, although I have successfully created a DLL, and put it in the extensions folder, and told php.ini about it, now I get this:

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: \x81\xc2\xc0\x03L&\xc0\x03: Unable to initialize module\nModule compiled with module API=16777522\nPHP    compiled with module API=20090626\nThese options need to match\n in Unknown on line 0

**Warning**:  PHP Startup: ÂÀL&À: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=16777522
PHP    compiled with module API=20090626
These options need to match
 in **Unknown** on line **0**

It seems that my PHP_API_VERSION is 20090626, but for some reason my DLL thinks it's PHP_API_VERSION is 16777522.

The tutorial below was some help in compiling an extension dll: 
http://www.talkphp.com/vbarticles.php?do=article&articleid=49&title=creating-custom-php-extensions

Having written it myself, I have access to all of the source code for the php extension in question - But, where is it that I control the PHP_API_VERSION that ends up in the DLL?

I am compiling the dll successfully with Borland C++ Builder v5.5, not Visual Studio.

Here is the complete source, in case it matters:

```
// Needed to make following two #includes compatible with borland header files
void __fastcall __assume(int t) {
  return;
}
typedef unsigned int socklen_t;
typedef enum BOOL
{
  false=0,
  true
} bool;
// end Borland compatibility code

#include "php.h"
#include "zend_config.w32.h"
ZEND_FUNCTION(fetch_LinkGrammar_links);

zend_function_entry LinkGrammar_ext_functions[] = {
    ZEND_FE(fetch_LinkGrammar_links, NULL)
    {NULL, NULL, NULL}
};

zend_module_entry LinkGrammar_ext_module_entry = {
    STANDARD_MODULE_HEADER,
    "LinkGrammar Extension",
    LinkGrammar_ext_functions,
    NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL,
    "1.0",
    STANDARD_MODULE_PROPERTIES
};

ZEND_GET_MODULE(LinkGrammar_ext);

ZEND_FUNCTION(fetch_LinkGrammar_links)
{
    bool World = false;
    char *RetVal= "";
    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "|b", &World) == FAILURE)
    {
        RETURN_STRING("Missing Parameter", true);
    }
    if (World == true)
    {
        RetVal= "Hello World";
    }
    else
    {
        RetVal= "Hello";
    }

    RETURN_STRING(RetVal, true);
}
```

What can I change to eliminate the PHP Startup Error that the API must match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was the "Data Alignment" - My DLL was being compiled using "Word" alignment and it needed to be double-word.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're compiling against a different version of PHP than the one you're running.

Take a peek in php.h and look for `#define PHP_API_VERSION` -- that's what you're compiling against.

Is that the same version that's running on your server?

Answer (score 0):

Check your include paths, locate file php.h and check that the version there matches php that you are running (running version is found if you check phpinfo() output).

Answer (score 0):

You should change the API version in zend_modules.h to the API version which your PHP server indicates in phpinfo().

For example if the PHP Extension API in phpinfo() is 20090523, you should change the API number in zend_modules.h file to 20090523 and then rebuild your project.